# How can I create an on hover border/outline on floated images in a gallery?

Tags: html, css, gallery

Please excuse if this is a fairly basic question. I've trawled through Google and elsewhere, and haven't found a solution that works for me.

I am generating an image gallery with the following markup.

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a class="galleryimg">
    <img>
  </a>
  ....
</div>
```

The `.galleryimg` is repeated, based on the number of images in the gallery. It is alse floated left.

I want to create a `:hover` effect that outlines the selected image. I've tried using border (messes up the layout), outline (which sounds perfect in principle), and inset box shadow (which is rendered below the image).

Outline is very close to what I want to achieve. But the right and bottom outline is obscured by adjacent images floating above it.

So my question: how can I create an on hover border/outline effect on a gallery of linked images?

I'd really appreciate any ideas as to how others have tackled this. Thanks!!

**EDIT**

The images are abutting, with no white space between.

Answer (score 2):

HI you can used simply used css Tricks as like this

**css**

```
#example-one a img, #example-one a           { border: none; overflow: hidden; float: left; }
#example-one a:hover                         { border: 3px solid black; }
#example-one a img{width:100px;height:50px;}
#example-one a:hover img                     { margin: -3px;}​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/QkT7d/3/

more about this click here http://css-tricks.com/examples/InnerBorderImages/#

Comment: thanks azad. Sorry I omitted a critical point from my question. The images are abutting with no white space between.

Comment: Hi i have updated my answer i thing you search like this  http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/QkT7d/3/

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/hMNZE/

Might be the desired effect. You will experience slight changes to the image as it makes itself smaller to allow for the border. but do let me know. This is only a quick fix.

---EDIT---

http://jsfiddle.net/hMNZE/2/

is a second version using negative margin, this looks okay but the images overlap a little.

Check out link: http://css-tricks.com/examples/InnerBorderImages/

---EDIT2---

http://jsfiddle.net/hMNZE/3/ is the best

---EDIT3---

```
.gallery {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px;
}

.galleryimg {
    float:left
}

.galleryimg img {
    z-index:-10;
}

.galleryimg img:hover {
    margin:-2px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    z-index:9999;
}​
```

Comment: Hi Philip, thanks for this. This works great! However I'm keen to avoid defining the element width/height in the css, as this is being applied in a Rails app and image dimensions can be adjusted by the user. Is there a way around this?

Comment: On the third fiddle you do not have to use width/height but just negative margins... (See EDIT2)

Comment: but you still have a gap between the 2 lines

Comment: that is just the fiddle, if your images are already lined up how you like then just apply border and make your negative margin the same relative size. will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

if you use `box-sizing` property (supported since `IE8`) you could add the border on `:hover` without messing up the layout

```
.galleryimg {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width : 100px;
    float : left;
}

.galleryimg:hover {
    border  : 3px gray solid;
}
```

see http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ for more info on this property

Comment: thanks f. calderan. this is a pretty good solution. However this is being used in a dynamic rails app. As image sizes may be altered via the user, I'm reluctant to hard code the width into the css. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vvr7C/
The trick is to add the padding on .gallery so you'll see the outline also on the images that are on the edge od the gallery:

```
.gallery {padding:2px}
.galleryimg:hover img {outline: red solid 2px}​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **box-shadow** & it's come below the other image then write like this:

```
.gallery img:hover{
 padding:0;
 box-shaow:0 0 0 2px red;
 z-index:1;
}
.gallery img{position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question was answered above, great. If not, it sounds like you might need some margin between the images and other objects around. You said it was obscured. It might just need 2px or so worth of margin to unobscure it.

Comment: hi ilBeatz. Yes a margin would reveal the border. However images are displayed directly abutting each other, with no white space between. Applying a margin would break this design. I was hoping that insert shadow would work, seems strange that it is rendered below the image.

Comment: You do an inverted box shadow on the images but that would only work in browsers that support box shadow. box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000000;

Answer (score 0):

hi you can do this thing easily via **CSS3** **box-shadow** property:-

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.9);
```

see the demo for better understanding :- http://jsbin.com/upedel/5/edit

**UPDATED ANWSER**

Please see the updated demo:- http://jsbin.com/upedel/10/edit

Comment: thanks shailender. unfortunately box shadow is rendered below enclosed images. hence I've been unable to use this easily. I'm sure its possible with some manipulation, surrounding elements, etc. I wondered whether anyone had a more elegant solution though.

Comment: Hey @AndyHarvey yes you have to do some manipulation with the mention above demo but i hope this will full-fill your requirement once you will play deeply with CSS because its demo kind for you....